# Can I legally refuse entry to a landlord?

Tags: rental-property, germany, landlord, residential-lease, tenant

I am subletting an apartment from a friend who is technically my landlord. I refused him entry late at night after we had a row about a longstanding problem with one of the facilities in the apartment I just moved in to. The friend is angry at me saying that I "Refused him entry to his own room", and sent messages requesting his room back within a week.

There was no notice given before he wanted to enter the room, it was just something he decided after we had already met that night.

Can I legally refuse entry to a landlord?

Comment: Is subletting legal in your area?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In general, a German landlord needs to give at least 24 hours notice before he can enter a home, and allowance from the renter. The renter also has the "Hausrecht", not the landlord.

<sup>There are exceptions, most of them to prevent damage from an ongoing danger threatening the house. A clear example would be a broken water pipe.</sup>

1 week notice also appears to violate tenant laws - I hope you have a written contract about the subletting.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120106/discussion-on-answer-by-trish-can-i-legally-refuse-entry-to-a-landlord).